# Typescript - Reading data from a file as object returning undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am ready so data from a file which looks like this in the file:

```
const config = {
  appName: 'my app',
};
```

It also returns on if I console.log the variable data like this:

```
const config = {
  appName: 'my app',
};
```

So, I know that the data is there in variable called 'data'

the problem starts here:

When I try `console.log(data.config.appName)` I get undefined.

Do I have to convert it? How can I fix this so I can read the values?

Comment: How are you reading the file which contains the data? Show us code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
console.log(config.appName)
```

Comment: what happens when you do console.log(data)?